# How to Affine transform hundred images OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, affinetransform

I have hundred of images of the same printed product. In order to do inspection on this printed material, first I need to realign the object in the image.

I masked the ROI and find the orb matches between the first image (that I treat as a master sample) and the input image (to be aligned as the master).

I selected the highest score with nearest location score to be used as the point in affine transform. However, instead of translating the image, it appears to be flipped.

Here's the snippet of my code

```
def findMatches(img,mask):
size = mask.shape[0]*mask.shape[1]
orb = cv2.ORB_create(size,
                         edgeThreshold=15, 
                         patchSize=31, 
                         nlevels=8, 
                         fastThreshold=20, 
                         scaleFactor=1.2, 
                         WTA_K=2,
                         scoreType=cv2.ORB_HARRIS_SCORE, 
                         firstLevel=0)

#Compute ORB KeyPoints and Descriptor in mask area 
kp_ori, dc_ori = orb.detectAndCompute(mask, None)    

img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(mask,kp_ori,outImage = None,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()

#Match the point with the original image back


#Compute ORB KeyPoints and Descriptor in input image 
kp_inp, dc_inp = orb.detectAndCompute(inp, None)
#kp_inp = [i for i in kp_inp if i.pt[1] > cnt_raveled[0][1] and i.pt[1] < cnt_raveled[1][1] 
#         and i.pt[0] > cnt_raveled[0][0] and i.pt[0] > cnt_raveled[2][0]]

img3 = cv2.drawKeypoints(inp,kp_inp,outImage = None,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()

matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
matches = matcher.match(dc_ori, dc_inp, None)

matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)
matches = [x for x in matches if x.distance < 5]

img4 = cv2.drawMatches(mask,kp_ori,inp,kp_inp,matches[:10],None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
plt.imshow(img4)
plt.show()

return matches,kp_ori,kp_inp
```

and then

```
pt1 = ((0,0),kp_ori1[matches1[0].imgIdx].pt,kp_ori2[matches2[0].imgIdx].pt)
pt2 = ((0,0),kp_inp1[matches1[0].queryIdx].pt,kp_inp2[matches2[0].queryIdx].pt)

rows,cols = inp.shape

M = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(pt1),np.float32(pt2))

dst = cv2.warpAffine(inp,M,(cols,rows))
dst = cv2.warpAffine(inp,M,(cols,rows))
```

But the output appear like this..

Comment: Where is the output?  A flip often occurs because you have x and y swapped. Note that x.shape returns height, width. You are assigning them to size. OpenCV needs size as width, height.

Comment: I don't know why I cant attached the image. But thank you for that info, I'll check again if it's mismatched between the X and Y

Comment: You have to have a certain number of points to be able to post images on this forum. But you can post to some free image hosting service and put the URLs here